# How to Get session values in default.ctp in cake php3

Tags: php, variables, session, cakephp

```
$this->Auth->user ( 'username' );
```

is working perfectly fine in controller but I want to check whether any user is logged in or not in default.ctp file using

```
$this->Auth->user ();
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Instead of default.ctp it is better to check in App Controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
```

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to check for an authenticated user in your view using arilia method, you should do it in your controller and then send it to the view. One easy way is the following (in your AppController):

```
public function beforeRender (Cake\Event\Event $event) {
    $this->set('isAuthenticatedUser', (bool) $this->Auth->user('username')) ;
    return parent::beforeRender ($event) ;
}
```

Using the above, in any of your view you will have access to the `$isAuthenticatedUser` variable telling you if a user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->request->Session()->Write('sessionname' ,$value);
$this->request->Session()->read('sessionname');
```

`$value` is the value which we have to write in the session and `sessionname` is a variable.

Comment: You should explain your code and why it helps. Also I think `echo'$value';` is not what you wanted to write.

Comment: $value is the value which we have to write in the session and sessionname is a variable. it is for cake php 3x

Comment: It's not about the meaning of `$value`, it's about your PHP: `echo'$value';` just echoes `$value`, not the content of the variable. That's basic PHP, not related to Cake

Comment: ohh ys i knew this .. by mistake i write the varible in single cots----- its "$value";